# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found in laravel project when using query builder selectRaw clause

Tags: php, laravel-8

In my laravel project, i am trying to get aggregate of order total from `orders` table joined with `order_products` table. But getting the following error when using table alias in `selectRaw` clause.

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'orders.total' in 'field list' (SQL: select SUM(orders.total) as total,order_products.name from `tm_orders` inner join `tm_order_products` on `tm_order_products`.`order_id` = `tm_orders`.`order_id` group by order_products.name)
```

The query builder code for the corresponding error is given below

```
$result = DB::table('orders')
            ->selectRaw('SUM(orders.total) as total,order_products.name')
            ->join('order_products', 'order_products.order_id', '=', 'orders.order_id')
            ->groupByRaw('order_products.name')
            ->get();
```

[image: order table columns]

Comment: Can you share the columns that your database table has? Because it's hard to spot what is going wrong at database level if we do not have any insights into the database structure.

Comment: Also, the query states that you're joining the table from `tm_orders` on `tm_order_products`. Didn't you perhaps mean to `->selectRaw('SUM(tm_orders.total))..` instead of `SUM(orders.total)..` ?

Comment: @KayAngevare added the image of orders table

Comment: @KayAngevare Actually the problem arrives when using table alias in selectRaw clause

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your query from below

`$result = DB::table('orders')`

`->join('order_products', 'order_products.order_id', '=', 'orders.order_id')`

`->groupByRaw('order_products.name')`

`->selectRaw('SUM(orders.total) as total,order_products.name')`

`->get();`

If you want to use selectRaw function so for that you need to use after fetching all details.
Let me know in comment now you are able to get sum of total or not.
Feel free to ask i will be available for answer.